# "this function is inappropriate for file system directories" when performing @DbLookup

Tags: lotus-domino

When I do a @DbLookup, in certain cases I get the error

```
"this function is inappropriate for file system directories"
```

The documentation found elsewhere on the Web states that this is probably a misspelling of the view name, but it is not the case here. Other suggestions point to invalid characters in the view name. Again, not the case. What could be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

With more than 20 years of Lotus experience, I thought I had seen everything, but no... I just ran into this one for the first time yesterday!

You've got something wrong with the database path that you are passing in the arguments. It probably ends in "/".

I ran into it while constructing an isolated test case to try and reproduce a production problem. I was copying pieces of the affected form into a new form one at a time and testing, and I got this error.

It was caused by @DbLookup code that calculated the path and filename for the target database, like this:

```
@DbLookup("Notes":"NoCache"; theServer : "MyFolder/" + theDatabase; etc., etc.
```

I had not copied the field `theDatabase`  from the production form to the test form, so it was just an uninitialized value. That left me with "MyFolder/" as the argument, so it looks like I'm trying to do an @DbLookup against an entire folder. From that point of view, the error message actually makes perfect sense.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem for a while and finally found out that I was using the hierarchical of the server, which does not seem to be supported. After turning it into the abbreviated form, it worked. Also, for some reason, I had to `@Trim` and then `@Text` it before it worked. The final solution went like this:

```
_abbreviatedServerName := @Text(@Trim(@Name([ABBREVIATE]; _serverName)));
_result := @DbLookup("":"NoCache"; _abbreviatedServerName : _databaseName; _viewName; _key; _column; [FailSilent]);
```